# Pygame works in Terminal, Not in Pycharm

Tags: python-2.7, pygame, pycharm

I am on OS X El Capitan using Python 2.7. I installed pygame and it resides in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages. When running from terminal I can import the module just fine but when I go to PyCharm I get the "no module named pygame." Under the Project Interpreters Pygame is listed as below.
[image]

I have attempted to copy the pygame folder from the above directory to the same directory as numpy with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed my situation. I had to delete the old project I had created before moving the pygame files into the other directory. Hitting the synchronize button did not update the external libraries as I had thought.